# How to understand the "Availability" of the CAP theorem?

Tags: dc.distributed-comp, db.databases, availability

As we know, in [the CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem), "A" means "Availability". On wikipedia, the explanation of "Availability" is:

> Availability: a guarantee that every request receives a response about
>   whether it was successful or failed

However, from the perspective of engineering, there is no ABSOLUTE availability. We can only say that the availability of a system is 5'9'(99.999%), or even 8'9', but we cannot say that the availability of a system is 100%, 100% available system does not exit in reality, even if the system has millions of duplicated nodes, right?

The CAP theorem proves that no system could satisfy the 3 requirements simultaneously. My question is, if a system claims to satisfy both "A" and "P", what is the accurate meaning of this "A"? 6'9' or even higher?

Comment: I see this question is cross posted from stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069147/how-to-understand-the-availability-of-the-cap-theorem.

Comment: Yes, I think this question is more suitable to be posted here.

Comment: I think that taking 100% or <100% values for the Availability is ininfluent, because it is "masquerade" by the arbitrary message loss in the Partition tolerance. The *availability* definition used by Brewer is "Every request received by a non-failling node in the system must result in a response. 
That is, any algorithm used by the service must eventually
terminate. ..."

Answer (score 3):

Your question is mixing two somewhat orthogonal interpretations of the term "Availability".

- The "reliability theory"/"engineering" interpretation, where availability is basically
  the ratio of time the system is not failed.
- The "distributed computing" interpretation, which is centered around the idea that

  > "every request received by a non-failing node in the system must result in a response"

So, let's consider a system of two nodes, that crash at midnight, and are resume operation at noon, every day.

So in the first interpretation we have 50% availability, that is, no nines at all. However, the system can still fulfill the second interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

The "Availability" in the CAP Theorem can be regarded as a classic liveness property: every request *eventually* receives a response. It is interpreted in [Perspectives on the CAP Theorem](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/tds/papers/Gilbert/Brewer2.pdf) in the context of distributed computing.

> Obviously, a fast response is better than a slow response,
>   but for the purpose of CAP, it turns out that even requiring an eventual response is sufﬁcient to create problems. (In
>   most real systems, of course, a response that is sufﬁciently late is just as bad as a response that never occurs.)

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that The CAP Theorem Is Not a Theorem. The CAP properties in the conjecture by Brewer are simply not well-defined enough to provide a rigorous mathematical proof. So, the reason availability is hard to "understand" could be because it is simply not well-defined in this context.

Comment: Please make your answer self-contained, rather than expecting readers to follow a link to your blog (which can look like the main purpose, when somebody's first post contains such a link).